# Regex: string between a mix of constant and variable characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string (fulltext). It's made of a part that is the name of a built-in function and of a second part that is the description. 
I want to extract the description.

i.e. I want to extract the part of the text that is between `\rPython *function_name*()\r` and this `\r`
so the outcome would be "returns class method for given function"

I've tried this `r'(?<=\\rPython .()\\r)(.*?)(?=\\r)'` but it doesn't show any result found and I don't know why.

```
#find description
fulltext=r'\rPython classmethod()\rreturns class method for given function\r'
description_regex=re.compile( r'(?<=\\rPython .()\\r)(.*?)(?=\\r)')
description= description_regex.search(fulltext)
print(description.group())
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples of input text?

Comment: it 's the variable fulltext in the code I've pasted, if you need it I can paste the whole document I'm working on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` here:

```
input = "\rPython classmethod()\rreturns class method for given function\r"
matches = re.findall(r'\rPython\s+[^()]+\(\)\r(.*)\r', input)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['returns class method for given function']
```

Using `re.findall` might make sense if you have a text which you might expect to have more than one possible match.